# Azure functions and Web Jobs Tools extension update failed

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

Visual studio 2017 entreprise (15.9.5) display a notification for an update to "Azure function and Web Jobs extension tools".

I tried to update the Azure functions and Web Jobs Tools extension (current version 15.0.30923.0 to 15.10.2046.0) from the menu tools/extensions and updates. The update is downloaded but the visx installer fails with the message

> "This extension is already installed to all applicable products"

I already uninstall/reinstall the azure workload from the visual studio installer.
I also tried to delete the folder : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools Azure\WebJobs`

Any clue on how to fix this and get the latest version of the extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to update by deleting two directories containing the extension:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools Azure\WebJobs
```

and another folder located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions`.

The extension was no longer present in visual studio and I was able to manually add it from the menu extension tools/market place in visual studio.